# How to handle python module installation when running jupyter notebook in docker?

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently starting to use the awesome jupyter notebook. Since I've always had troubles with stuff not working because of different python versions and python module versions, I like to run jupyter notebook in a docker container. I've created a `Dockerfile` to build my image (based on the official jupyter/scipy-notebook image on dockerhub), I have everything up and running and its working great.

The only thing that concerns me is how to handle the installation of different python modules I might need during the next week(s). How do you guys handle that?

1) Install the needed modules in the running docker container, then use `docker commit` and save the running container as a new image?

2) Always edit the `Dockerfile` to install the needed modules and re-build the image?

3) Don't delete the container (no `--rm` flag) and just restart it?

1) and 2) seem to be a little complicated, but I also want to be able to be able to start from a "fresh" notebook in case I mess something up, so 3) is also not perfect. Is there something I missed?