# How to *securely* setup Jupyter-Notebook runnnig CUDA enabled PyTorch, inside docker, on a dedicated server in the internet?

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

Gladly we are beyond basic setup things or questions like [How to handle python module installation when running jupyter notebook in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47203010/how-to-handle-python-module-installation-when-running-jupyter-notebook-in-docker), [Best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/)

This server already is running in our local intranet,
we are already using this as collaborative deep-learning dev-server for our team.

Our Team gets more distributed and now we are going to move this server into
an own DMZ to e.g. allow team acces via normal internet (and: not just via VPN).

The question therefore mainly is, how to *securely* do this, configure, user, permissions ...

Currently we installed cuda drivers etc. on the (Ubuntu) host,
use nvidia-docker to get cuda into the docker containers.
To make all cuda drivers of all containers compatible with the cuda version of host,
we are using manual dockerfile based aproach, where all containers derive from base image

```
nvcr.io/nvidia/cuda  9.0-cudnn7.1-devel-ubuntu16.04
```

(From there a intermediate dockerfile installs further things) but finally the final dockerfile 
esp. (pip-) installs jupyter-notebook together with the needed (e.g. PyTorch 0.4.1) and all other needed deep-learning tools.

The docker container is started by adding a shared volume to the docker container,
i.e. a folder on the host belonging to docker:docker with group sticky bit.
Therein have the actual machine-learing code for the Jupyter-notebooks.

```
nvidia-docker run --runtime=nvidia \
  --interactive --tty \
  --volume /srv:/srv \
  --name ${CONT_NAME} \
  --hostname ${CONT_HOSTNAME} \
  ${IMAGE_FULLNAME}
```

Another script then starts inside the container the notebook with a dedicated AUTH token,
that is regularly shared among the users of this jupyter notebook.

```
jupyter notebook --allow-root --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser --NotebookApp.token='<TEMP_AUTH_TOKEN>'
```

The DMZ firewall allows web-access to this single port of the Jupyter-Notebook only.

The notebook (together with the GPU related python code) needs access to the cuda toolchain and the GPUs.
This is passed in by nvidia-docker wrapper,
and we currently run all stuff inside the docker container as *root*.

Now *here* is my need for help: How would we secure this, "all within reason"?
(Alas, my job is not to be a full-time admin, but be the deep-learning guy)
I have an esp. "little bad feeling" offering a Jupyter-notebook running as root (even if root of container) to the web.
I fear hacking Jupyter-Notebook, and already as root inside container execute stuff would be one thing. But from there escape this docker container and own the whole host... how would I hinder such scenarios?

So on the one side: Jupyter needs to run and access CUDA-GPU of the host, but also serve the notebook to the web...

I would very apreciate more explanatory answers, hinting also some in-depth tipps/resources
for this kind of adventures, so I actually become more professional...